# If statement on args giving odd outputs

Tags: c++, if-statement, std

When running this code: `./a.out 5 + 5` i am supposed to get 10. but instead i get `Unkown operator.` does anyone know why this may be happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argv[2]=="+"){
        std::cout << std::stoi(argv[1])+std::stoi(argv[3]) << "\n";
    }
    else if (argv[2]=="-"){
        std::cout << std::stoi(argv[1])-std::stoi(argv[3]) << "\n";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Unkown operator." << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot compare c-strings with `==`

Comment: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ auto args = vector<string>(argv+1, argv+argc); ...`

Comment: Before you look at argv you should verify that argc is large enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is comparing pointer values, and not the strings data they point to...

```cpp
    if (argv[2]=="+"){
```

Either use strcmp:

```cpp
    if (strcmp(argv[2], "+") == 0){
    }
```

Or something along these lines:

```cpp
    if (std::string(argv[2]) == "+"){
    }
```